# Finding the Fourier Transform with Heaviside Step Function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am having some trouble trying to evaluate the integral of this F.T.

We are to take the definition for a continuous F.T:

$$
\mathcal{F} [g(t)] = G(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{-i2\pi ft})g(t) dt
$$

Where $g(t)$ is the an exponential function: $g(t) = e^{-t/\tau} H(t)$

Where H(t) is the Heaviside step function and is defined as:

$$
H(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1, & t \gt 0 \\
0, & t \le 0
\end{array}\right.
$$

I have an initial attempt of the integral worked out but upon evaluation I get an answer that is undefined.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Kindly use Mathjax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/25054

Comment: Hint: replace $g(t)$ in the integral, change the limits accordingly and carry out the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\tau>0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{g\}(f)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t/\tau}e^{-i2\pi ft }\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\left.\left(\frac{e^{-(\frac1\tau+i2\pi f)t}}{-(\frac1\tau+i2\pi f)}\right)\right|_{t=0}^{t=L}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac1\tau+i2\pi f}
\end{align}$$